# Selenium XML/Propeerties file Test suite?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I wanted to configure which selenium tests to run and which not to by either XML or through the properties file.

Example

```
testCase1=false
testCase2=true
testCase3=true
```

Now if I start selenium tests, it must run only 2 and 3.

Any possibility?

Also, do I need multiple ports to run tests simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `TestNG` you can use `@Test(enabled = false)` i.e., `enabled` argument for @Test annotation. See here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_ignore_test.htm

Comment: "@Test(enabled = false)" goes in to a class file once we build the project. But i want to configure on a properties file or xml.

Comment: Do you want to execute multiple classes or test methods in a class?

Answer (score 0):

`I wanted to configure which selenium tests to run and which not to by either XML or through properties file.`

It depends on which framework you use to run the tests.

For JUnit you can use `@Ignore` to skip the test method.

For TestNG you can make the test method `enabled=false` as [German Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2454841/german-petrov) answered

There are plenty of information available over internet. Google it.

```
Also do i need multiple ports to run tests simultaneously?
```

No, you don't need multiple ports, you can set parallel test execution, and TestNG provides better support to it.